# GO HTTP server hanging

Tags: http, go, server

I'm trying to run this example of code but it just hangs and doesn't print anything out - any ideas?

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
    fmt.Println("Hi")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Hello)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried issuing a request to `localhost:8080`?

Comment: *"it just hangs and doesn't print anything out"* -- Have you actually sent a request to the server? If so, can you show/explain how?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial here (see "HTTP Server"): https://scotch.io/tutorials/moving-from-nodejs-to-go

Comment: How would I get the "Hello World" to print in my console?

Comment: @andredms start the server and then run `curl localhost:8080` from a separate shell session. Or navigate to `localhost:8080` in your browser which will render the `"Hello World"` text and the shell session that's running the server will output `"Hi"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.Open up your browser such as Chrome and go to localhost:8080 or 127.0.1:8080 and you will see the output

Your code listens on a local port 8080, accepts a request from the client, and responds to the client with the corresponding data.

Your responds to client is "Hello World".

```
w.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
```

The key is the `http.HandleFunc` function,http.HandleFunc binds to a route that executes the Hello function whenever you access 127.0.0.1:8080 from your browser .The browser will response you "Hello World" and Program will print "Hi".